# Can you retrain RAKE?

Tags: python, nlp, rake, keyword-extraction

Is it possible to retrain RAKE (Rapid automatic keyword extractor)?

If so, how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. RAKE is an unsupervised, domain independent model that extracts keywords using patterns in the documents it sees at runtime. There's no training step in RAKE but you can change how it behaves by:

- Providing different stopword lists
- Changing parameters available in the particular RAKE implementation you are using, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/fabianvf/python-rake) lets you set minimum word frequency thresholds for keywords extracted.